# Styles for inputs don't appear to work on an iPad

Tags: css, ipad, safari

I have a few text input fields, two of which are disabled, they look right on the PC browser but when I look at it on the iPad the color of the text doesn't change to what it is meant to.

[image]

I have this style on disabled fields:

```
input[disabled='disabled']
{
    color:#555;
}
```

But the iPad doesn't seem to take notice of it.

Any ideas? This happens for all disabled input text fields.

Comment: Calibri, pretty standard font.

Comment: Thanx for answering...+1 for polite and reply...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this safari version **doesn't** support your css sadly you have to use extra classes on your fields like `class="disabled"`

Comment: I also have that class just sitting there for this. Didn't expect to use it though. Would I be able to test with normal safari and get the same response?

Comment: input:disabled
{
color: #555;
}

should work on every "normal" browser including safari ... but I'm still not sure if it works on IPad

Comment: Doesn't work on Safari on my computer. Produces the same effect on both.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to override the opacity, it works for me.

```
input:disabled {
   -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
   -webkit-opacity: 1; 
}
```